# Restart java ServerSocket with new port

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function to restart my ServerSocket with new port. The new port is provided by the user through the panel (that part of code is correct) in which the restart() function is colled. The new port is saved to the static field portNumString.

The following is my code of the attempt to restart the server. The restarted server is not working. The original port works correctly.

```
 public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
   {         
      runServer(false);
   } 


 public static void runServer(boolean changePort)
   {        
      try
        {
           ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(portNumString));
           Server server = new Server(socket);

           while(!changePort)
             {             
               server.accept();  

               if(changePort && socket!=null)
                 {
                   socket.close();                  
                   runServer(false);
                 }                    
             } 
        }
      catch(Exception e)
        {
           System.out.println("EXCEPTION !!! "+e);              
        }        
   }


 public static void restart() throws NumberFormatException, ClassNotFoundException, IOException
   {
      System.out.println("Restart Called... ");
      runServer(true);
   }
```

EDIT:

The part of code that calls the restart()

```
         cloesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                       {
                          @Override
                          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                            {                                  
                               portNumString=txtPort.getText();                                   
                               try
                                {
                                  restart();
                                }
                              catch(NumberFormatException e1)
                                {
                                  e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                       });
```

Comment: `runServer` runs an endless loop - is this multithreaded?

Comment: It is not multithreaded. The question is how to correct it

Comment: @Annabelle It must be multi-threaded... otherwise how are you even calling `restart()` while the server socket part is inside the while loop? The server's main thread will block on `accept()`, so another thread is calling the `restart()`

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming `restart()` is being called from another thread, since the `runServer` method has a loop that never terminates (since `changePort` is a local parameter and nothing changes it inside the loop)

`restart()` is not stopping the existent server.

It is just going through the method again starting a **new** `ServerSocket`, with the old one still running.

Since the boolean `changePort` is true, it won't even go inside the `while` loop, and never accepts a client socket. On the other hand the old server socket is still happily running.

In order to get this working properly you need to use a proper class, instead of a bunch of `static` methods. Put things like the port number and the `serverSocket` as member variables. Then check those in your while loop, without calling the method again. Something like:

```
while (true) {
   this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.portNum);

   try {   
     Socket client = server.accept();  

      //todo: do something with the client
   } 
   catch (IOException ex) { 
      //an IO error occurred, probably we were asked to restart
   }
}
```

Then you can have something like:

```
void restart(int portNum) {
  this.portNum = portNum;
  try {
    this.serverSocket.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
    //todo: handle it or log it somewhere
  }
}
```

Comment: I added the part of code that calls restart(). I know that my code is not working. The question is how to fix it.

Comment: Well I gave you the reason why it isn't working. I added some suggestions how you would do it.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to check the proposition

Comment: I cannot make it work. I am receiving "EXCEPTION !!! java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind"

Comment: That means you didn't close the previous server and you are trying to open another one again on the same port.

Comment: Your answer is not helpful because I cannot fix my code based on your answer

Comment: @Annabelle You are expecting people to write the code for you. I am telling you what the problem with your code is, and gave you some guidelines what to do. If you want someone to write complete code for you pay someone.

Comment: Do not be unfair. Your code is not working for me so I cannot accept this answer as a solution. Perhaps your suggestions are right, but I can not confirm this because no matter how I try it is not a bit better

Comment: I am clearly telling you that your approach is wrong and doesn't even make sense. I am telling you to change your design to have a separate class where the port number and the server socket are *member variables*. If you put my code in this new class it *will* work. When `restart()` is called the *member* variable is updated with the new port number, the old server socket is closed, the `accept()` in the while loop will throw the IOException, and the loop restarts, reopening the server socket with the new port number. If the port number was the same as the old it won't matter.